# Valgrind: is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I have a struct "Turing" with an array of "Breakpoints" witch has a char array inside.

When i call calloc

```
machine.breakpoints_[free_counter].type_ = calloc(6, sizeof(char));
```

and do nothing with it valgrind doesn't complain when i free it.

but when i assign something to the variable for example:

```
machine.breakpoints_[free_counter].type_ = "12345";
```

valgrind raises an error when i use free on this variable.

Structs:

```
typedef struct _Breakpoint_
{
  char value_;
  char* type_;
} Breakpoint;

typedef struct _Turing_
{
  char* band_;
  int head_position_;
  int start_state_;
  int current_rule_;
  int current_state_;
  int rules_count_;
  Rules* rules_;
  Breakpoint* breakpoints_;
  int breakpoint_counter_;
  Boolean turing_over_;
} Turing;
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Turing machine = {NULL, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, FALSE};

    machine.breakpoints_ = calloc(50, sizeof(Breakpoint));
    if(!machine.breakpoints_)
    {
      free(machine.breakpoints_);
      machine.breakpoints_ = NULL;
      printf(OUT_OF_MEMORY);
      return ERROR_CODE_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }

    int free_counter = 0;
    machine.breakpoints_[free_counter].type_ = calloc(6, sizeof(char));
    machine.breakpoints_[free_counter].type_ = "12345";
    machine.breakpoint_counter_++;

    for (; free_counter < machine.breakpoint_counter_; free_counter++)
    {
      free(machine.breakpoints_[free_counter].type_);       //line 133
      machine.breakpoints_[free_counter].type_ = NULL;
    }

    free(machine.breakpoints_);
    machine.breakpoints_ = NULL;
}
```

Valgrind is giving me this error:

```
==16989== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==16989==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16989==    by 0x400A95: main (assb.c:133)
==16989==  Address 0x401b18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

and:

```
==16989== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16989==     in use at exit: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==16989==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 806 bytes allocated
==16989== 
==16989== 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==16989==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16989==    by 0x400A50: main (assb.c:127)
```

What is wrong with my memory management there?

Please, tell me, if you nee further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"12345"` is a string literal. They are not "stack'd or malloc'd", they are like global static variables. You cannot free one of these.

As you saw from your line

```
p = calloc(6, 1);
```

you would know that using `=` on pointer means to make the pointer point to the same thing that the right-hand side points to  (in other words, `p` now holds the address you assigned to it).

The line

```
p = "12345";
```

is no different, you are making `p` stop pointing to the calloc'd space, and start pointing to the location of `"12345"`.

If you intended to copy from the location of `"12345"` into the location pointed to by `p`, you're going to need to use some dereference operators, or a predefined function such as `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `strcpy` to copy the string into your value. Right now you're overwriting the `calloc`'d pointer to a string that's actually in your executable binary.